# Good practice to store Data in $_SESSION from inside a function

Tags: php

Is it good  practice  to  store  Data in $_SESSION  from inside a function,I know  echoing  from  inside  a  function  is a  bad  practice.

Comment: It doesn't matter, whether u store data in session inside function or outside.

Comment: The `$_SESSION` is a super global array and it can even be accessed inside inner functions.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to create Handler that handles all the Session data, with methods to pull and push data to and from the session.

Comment: Right  we  can  Pass  error  to  a error handler function ?

Comment: You could make an error handler as well, just keep in mind, the "best practic" is to keep the logic separate.